# SQL Server : transaction log backup error Error 3013

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am not a database administrator. Our DBA left the organization on bad terms about a month ago and I am a application developer and didn't knew anything about database administration about a week ago, so please bear with me.

We have two servers, Server A (primary server) and Server B (secondary server). Mirroring was configured between A and B.

A was configured to replicate our DB tables to C (reporting server). Replication was configured on between A and C

A went down due to hardware failure (hard drives corrupted); B now is our only server.

A was down so our replication broke between A and C.

B was acting as our principal server now. Note that we were already low on disk space (different configurations of both servers), unusual behavior was observed that the disk space was being filled up so quickly.When the disk space was full the error encountered was “the transaction log for database ‘DBName’ is full due to ‘REPLICATION’.”

Note that the replication between B and C was not configured.

We faced a downtime of 18 hours

During that downtime started replacing hard drives of A and reconfigured it from scratch (windows server installation, SQL server installation)

We then copied the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files from B to our fresh A and restored them.

We are now on our A (primary) back again.

We bought a new server (D) to make work as our secondary server and restored the latest back up (`DBName.bak`) of fresh working A and the latest transaction log file backup (`DBName.trn`) taken after the full database backup. This was done to configure mirroring between A and D successfully.

We configured mirroring between A (primary) and D (secondary) successfully.

Now we are trying to configure replication between A (reporting) and C (reporting server) for that we need to make sure that our transnational log backup job is running which takes the backup and then shrinks the ldf files, the job runs after every 15 mins.This job is not running successfully. We notice an error with message ID 9003

Error :

> The log scan number (7796674:12164:1) passed to log scan in database ' DBName ' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup

We have read several blogs and articles proposing different solutions but the scenario doesn’t match to mine. I am confused to apply any of those solutions.

Currently we don’t have any replication configured. So the best solution a could read out of blogs were to apply sp_repldone which will remove or mark all the pending replication transactions as replicated from the transactions log files.

Given the above scenario should we be applying the above solution.

Comment: `sp_repldone` will result in missing data, don't do it, Also even though you claim to have replication setup between server A and Server C but it sounds a lot more like you have Log Shipping setup. "SQL Agent Job to take Log backup" this only happens in Log Shipping and not Replication.

Comment: If you are really using Replication between Server A and Server C , I would recommend taking another Full backup from Server A and then using that backup on the Server C to setup the Subscriber database.

Comment: @M.Ali I am sure we had a replication setup between Server A and Server C originally. On server C we have some tables from our database that resides on Server A. But since Server A is completely configured from scratch expect the replication we are now trying to reconfigure the replication. So the problem is in that SQL Agent Job that takes the log back up and shrinks it every 15 mins on Server A.

Comment: No where in replication process you have a job to take log backups, I don't know what you are talking about. Log backups has nothing to do with replication.

Comment: @M.Ali I am sorry if i sound confusing. 
The reason for explaining all the situation was just to be clear on my scenario.
The problem is in taking log file backup. which we must resolve before reconfiguration of replication. This error occurs when the job takes the log file backup.